# Read several html sources from a domain using one connection

Tags: java

I have some problems with a java app i'm developing, i'm using HtmlCleaner 2.2 library (the one used in web-harvest proyect) and have no problem getting the source of a page.

My problem starts when i want to recursively browse the site and get an tree of categories and products as childs. I guess that each time the script visits a page, it counts as a user entering the site, so when it visits 15 or 20 category or product pages, the website firewall blocks my ip for about an hour.

With this problem 2 solutions come to my mind, first: use proxys, i don't get banned and i can download faster using threads, second: open only one connection. I guess it's a bad idea to use proxies so i want to ask, in a simple code, **what is the best way to visit recursively about 300000 products of a website without being banned?** fastest and simple

Putting the source in a string it's enough to count as visited.
I don't want a debate about the best way, only a well justificated one.

**Acclaration: This is a school task, i'm not making any profit of this, and i'm trying to be the less harmful for the site**

Comment: Given your general disregard for the site you are spider-raping you'll probably disregard this but I would think doing the right thing and spidering them in one thread with some pauses between each request is in order.

Comment: Google has exactly the same problem.  I don't know, but I guess they solve it by spidering many, many sites in parallel and not attempting to overload any one given website with requests.

Comment: are you checking for a `robots.txt` file at the site you are DOSing and abiding by it?

Comment: i know the way my script is working it's similar to a DOS attack. i'm really respectful for the site, i run the script only the neccessary to test it, and don't want to "rape" the site, that why i ask this question, sorry for my bad english

Comment: It *is* a DOS attack, not just "similar to".  Your *intent* does not matter, you are overloading their infrastructure causing a potential denial of service.

Comment: ***intent*** has no bearing on what you are doing, [the first internet worm had good intentions as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) but caused widespread destruction and damage. If you aren't abiding by their desires you are not being a good internet citizen, I encourage everyone reading this to **not** help you with your endevour, regardless of why you are claiming to want to do this. The site you are doing this to considers it harmful, and in some jurisdictions it could be considered criminal as well.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson i don't know how to do that, if i knew, i don't be asking the best way to do it

Comment: can you use google? can you google `robots.txt`, I think you should just stop what you are doing, the site you are attacking deems it harmful enough to detect your actions and ban you, that or pick another site to DOS. Either way not good behavior of a netizen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your spidering provides legitimate business value to the site your are scraping, you could contact the website owner and ask for either a data feed or an exclusion to their banning algorithm (after all, it's often beneficial for people to have their products exposed to prospective buyers).

**UPDATE**

Based on your statement that this is a school task, ask your teacher for assistance in finding a website that is willing to be bombarded with traffic in the interest of education, or reach out to the website owner, explain what you are doing, and ask for permission.

Comment: thanks for the comment and the "homework" tag
i'll find a way to get the data without make a DoS without affect the site resources, but out of stackoverflow